# How many threads are in Dispatchers.IO?

Tags: http, kotlin, okhttp, kotlin-coroutines

I'm working on library what is based on okhttp3 for kotlin. Internally okhttp3 uses its own [Dispatcher](https://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/okhttp/okhttp3/Dispatcher.html) and it have fields, such as [maxRequests](https://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/okhttp/okhttp3/Dispatcher.html#setMaxRequests-int-) and [maxRequestsPerHost](https://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/okhttp/okhttp3/Dispatcher.html#setMaxRequestsPerHost-int-) that determines, how many requests can we send at the moment. I want to set amount of this requests equal to amount of coroutines in [Dispatchers.IO](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-dispatchers/-i-o.html) in kotlin, to have logic close to coroutines.

So, here are the questions:

1. How can we get the number of threads in [Dispatchers.IO](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-dispatchers/-i-o.html) scope from the program code? (Maybe there is some method/public constant that i didn't find)
2. Alternatively we can set this number manually by [Dispatchers.IO](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-dispatchers/-i-o.html) documentation. Kotlin developers write, that amount of threads "*defaults to the limit of 64 threads or the number of cores (whichever is larger)*". Will this information be changed or this fact is immutable?

Answer (score 3):

The answer is that you don't need the `IO` dispatcher to work with okhttp because it's an async HTTP library. The purpose of `Dispatchers.IO` is making blocking operations off the main UI thread. Async operations are to be performed on the `Main` dispatcher because they don't block the thread.